# Why can’t I get rid of the L with this python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I’m trying to get rid of the Ls at the ends of integers with a regular expression in python:

```
import re
s = '3535L sadf ddsf df 23L 2323L'
s = re.sub(r'\w(\d+)L\w', '\1', s)
```

However, this regex doesn't even change the string. I've also tried `s = re.sub(r'\w\d+(L)\w', '', s)` since I thought that maybe the L could be captured and deleted, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I think L stands for Long integer in python

Comment: can u show what is your expected output??

Comment: @abarnert oops lol ... I was trying to say the answer you posted ... but screwed it all up :P stupid parens :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with those `\w`s in the first place, but to match a string of digits followed by an `L`, just use `\d+L`, and to remove the `L` you just need to put the `\d+` part in a capture group so you can sub it for the whole thing:

```
>>> s = '3535L sadf ddsf df 23L 2323L'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)L', r'\1', s)
'3535 sadf ddsf df 23 2323'
```

Here's the regex in action:

```
(\d+)L
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fZnX5eCNS1t4bt1R)

Of course this will also convert, e.g., `123LBQ` into `123BQ`, but I don't see anything in your examples or in your description of the problem that indicates that this is possible, or which possible result you want for that, so…

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution(which is almost always the correct one imho)

Answer (score 2):

`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

---

In other words, `\w` does not include whitespace characters. Each `L` is at the end of the word and therefore doesn't have any "word characters" following it. Perhaps you were looking for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)?

```
re.sub(r'\b(\d+)L\b', '\1', s)
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/lP9fP5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use look behind assertion

```
>>> s = '3535L sadf ddsf df 23L 2323L'
>>> s = re.sub(r'\w(?<=\d)L\b', '', s)
>>> s
'353 sadf ddsf df 2 232'
```

`(?<=\d)L` asserts that the `L` is presceded by a digit, in which case replace it with null`''`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`re.sub(r'(?<=\d)L', '\1', s)`

This uses a lookbehind to find a digit followed by an "L".

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a - IMO more readable - `generator expression`?

```
>>> s = '3535L sadf ddsf df 23L 2323L'
>>> ' '.join(x.rstrip('L') if x[-1:] =='L' and  x[:-1].isdigit() else x for x in s.split())
'3535 sadf ddsf df 23 2323'
```